First Passage Time, Expectation, and Minimum of a Biased Random Walk
Question
I am working on a problem involving a one-dimensional biased random walk, where the steps are taken on the integers. The walk $\{S_n\}$ starts at $S_0=0$, and the step size $\xi$ follows a distribution where $P(\xi = 1) = p$ and $P(\xi = -1) = 1-p$, with $\frac{1}{2} < p < 1$. Let $\tau_k = \inf \{ n \geq 0 : S_n = k \}$ represent the first time the walk reaches $k$.

Find the probability $P_0(\tau_k = n)$, the probability that the walk first reaches $k$ at time $n$.
Compute the expected value $E_0(\tau_k)$, the expected first passage time to reach $k$.
Determine the probability distribution of the minimum $Y = \min \{S_0, S_1, \dots\}$.

My Attempt One
I recall from class the reflection principle and its implications for such problems. Using the reflection principle, the probability that $S_n = k$ (i.e., the walk is at position $k$ at step $n$) is:
$$P_0(S_n = k) = \binom{n}{\frac{n + k}{2}} p^{\frac{n + k}{2}} q^{\frac{n - k}{2}}$$
for $k \geq 0$. So we have
$$P_0(\tau_k = n) = \frac{|k|}{n} P_0(S_n = k).$$
Thus, the probability that the walker first reaches $k$ at time $n$ is:
$$P_0(\tau_k = n) = \frac{|k|}{n} \binom{n}{\frac{n + k}{2}} p^{\frac{n + k}{2}} q^{\frac{n - k}{2}}.$$
However, the reflection principle applies to symmetric random walks, and this walk is biased. Therefore, I am uncertain whether this approach is correct for the biased case.
My Attempt Two
For $k > 0$, the expected first passage time $E_0(\tau_k)$ is:
$$
E_0(\tau_k) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n P_0(\tau_k = n) = \frac{k}{p - q}.
$$
However, I am not confident in this result. I obtained this formula through symbolic manipulation, but I am unclear how to rigorously simplify the summation involving the binomial terms. I would appreciate clarification on how this result is derived or if there is a more appropriate method to compute the expectation.
Thank you!


Let $q=1-p<p$ and $Y_n=S_n-(p-q)n$. Then $Y_n$ is a martingale with respect to the filtration $\mathcal{F}_n=\sigma(S_0,S_1,\dots,S_n)$, and
$$
\mathbb{E}Y_{\tau_k}=\mathbb{E}[S_{\tau_k}-(p-q)\tau_k]=k-(p-q)\mathbb{E}\tau_k=Y_0=0
$$
by the Optional Stopping Theorem (part b).
so that $\mathbb{E}\tau_k=\frac{k}{p-q}$.

From Gambler's ruin, we know that for $a,b>0$ and $S_0=0$
$$
\mathbb{P}(S_n\text{ reaches $b$ before }-a)=\frac{1-(q/p)^a}{1-(q/p)^{a+b}}.
$$
By letting $b\to+\infty$, we see that
$$
\mathbb{P}(\min_{k\ge 0} S_k>-a)=\mathbb{P}(Y> -a)=1-(q/p)^a
$$
hence $-Y\in\{0,1,2,\dots\}$ has a geometric distribution (starting from zero) with parameter $q/p\in (0,1)$.


